# Change In Itinerary After Schengen Visa Granted

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I have got Schengen Visa from Italy (Consulate General of Mumbai) on April 30, 2019. I got Visa from June 8, 2019 - July 6, 2019 with validity of 15 days. I had previous visa from Embassy of Netherlands from June 8, 2018 - June 8, 2019 with validity of 90 days. I have already used 15 days in June 2018, 7 days in Jan 2019 for the Schengen Visa issued by Embassy of Netherlands in June 2018.

I told Consulate General of Mumbai that I'll travel on June 9, 2019 and stay till June 16, 2019, however, my employer is asking me to travel on June 1, 2019 and stay in Switzerland till June 8 and enter Italy on June 9 and stay there till June 22. I have two concerns:

1. Now I know in Schengen Visa Code this is allowed, but I am anxious like hell. My company is big on cost cutting and they are saying spending INR 150,000 (EUR 2000) on Return Business Flight is useless as you are allowed to enter on one visa and leave on another visa. This was already answered by another guy...
2. I am just scared that they will ask me why I didn't tell this earlier....Also another concern is that I will be returning on 22nd June (14th day) instead of regular on 16th June (9th Day) which I told Consulate. Please note I shall be returning before Visa Expiry and Visa Validity

Btw, I was suppose to travel to Switzerland in end of May and return on June 7, 2019 anyhow, but my employer is asking why I am returning and just travel on June 9, 2019 to Italy as Hotel cost is just INR 15,000 (EUR 200)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Holding overlapping Schengen visas, may I treat one as an extension without exiting?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138202/holding-overlapping-schengen-visas-may-i-treat-one-as-an-extension-without-exit)

Comment: @HenningMakholm not a duplicate even though much of question background is the same. Here the OP is interested in knowing whether they can extend the return dates after they have got the visa or will there be a problem

Comment: We already have a couple of similar questions: [this one about moving trips](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45800/can-i-change-my-flight-dates-after-i-get-my-schengen-visa) and [this one about staying for more days _and_ adding new countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116903/extending-itinerary-and-travelling-to-other-countries-on-schengen-visa). It looks like minor adjustements are OK but staying for significantly more days than originally planned may look bad, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Henning and RedBaron, my employer is okay with me coming back to India on June 7 (I think my employer just gave up in front on my stubbornness), however, my Manager in Switzerland thinks there should be no problem if I am travelling from Milan to Zurich / Zurich to Milan given I have taken the visa for Business Reasons and I am only travelling from Italy to Switzerland / Switzerland to Italy on Business trip. He asked me to get letters from company subsidy in Italy as well as from HQs in Switzerland. Now I am travelling on June 9 and returning on June 21, first I was intend to travel back on June 16. I am a very frequent traveler and I guess  this should be fine!

Btw I mailed Consulate General of Italy in Mumbai as well as Embassy of Italy in New Delhi about my further plans and they replied saying as "You could choose to stay not more than 15 days in Schengen Region valid from June 8 - July 6 2019"

Comment: Nice to know this is resolved. IMO it was never a problem for you to stay on two visas (your swiss manager is right). The main issue was changing return dates (which you are doing now too) but if the embassy says its fine, then I guess it is fine.